# remove any word using remove() in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to make a function that remove any specific word in the content

I got this code

**jQuery**

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cl').click(function(){
        $('div').remove(':contains("kamal")');
    });
    
    
})
</script>
```

**HTML**

```
<div>asdjh alsdhj kamal ljkahsdhasd lakshd kamal</div>
<div ><a href="#" id="cl">click</a></div>
<div>asdjh alsdhj  ljkahsdhasd lakshd </div>
```

but its remove whole `div` contains `kamal` I want to remove only this word from my content not the whole `div` you can also see online demo of my code [here](https://jsfiddle.net/zhV4D/)

Comment: `:contains("kamal")` selector doesn't find exact "kamal" words - it finds element containing this word. So instead of this use normal `.replace()` method.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct way to do a read-modify-write on an element is to use jQuery's "function parameter" methods:

```
$('div:contains(kamal)').filter(function() {
    return $(this).children().length === 0;  // exclude divs with children
}).text(function(index, text) {
    return text.replace(/kamal/g, '');
});
```

this avoids calling `.text()` twice, and also simplifies the code logic.

Note that you may get *unusual* results if you have nested `div` tags, since the `:contains()` pseudo selector considers *all* descendants, not just direct children, and does it top-down rather than bottom-up.  This is why the above solution includes the initial `.filter` call, to ensure that only leaf nodes in the DOM tree are considered.

An alternative method is to use `.contents` and look directly at DOM text nodes:

```
var re = /kamal/gi;

$('div').contents().each(function() {
    if (this.nodeType === 3 && this.nodeValue.match(re)) {
        this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(re, '');
    }
})​
```

See https://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/eVUd3/

**EDIT** second example updated to use `string.match(regex)` instead of `regex.test(string)`.

Answer (score 2):

This should work for you

```
 <script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
     $('#cl').click(function(){             
        var ka = /kamal/gi;

        $('div').contents().each(function() {

            // this.nodeType === 3 selects the text nodes section of the DOM
            // then ka.test(this.nodeValue) performs a regex test on the text 
            // in the node to see if it contains the word "kamal" with the 
            // global /g flag to search the entire string and /i to be case 
            // insensitive

            if (this.nodeType === 3 && ka.test(this.nodeValue)) {
                this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(ka, '');
            }
            // this section catches the text nodes within the child and 
            // performs the same operation
            $(this).contents().each(function() {
                if (this.nodeType === 3 && ka.test(this.nodeValue)) {
                     this.nodeValue = this.nodeValue.replace(ka, '');
                }
            })        
        })

     })
 });
 </script>
```

**edit**: changed the simple string replace with a global regex replace so one click replaces all instances.
see [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kamui/U7PT3/3/) for a working example.

**edit:** Based on the comment from @Alnitak who was correct in noting that the previous version of the code removed whole child elements containing the text not just the text, the new updated version does not disrupt the DOM and removes all instances of the key word *"kamal"* see updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/kamui/U7PT3/6/).

Comment: @Alnitak yes it will, check out the updated jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kamui/U7PT3/4/ I have the word of interest in a div within a div.

Comment: look more carefully - you'll find that your code actually removed the entire inner div because the _outer_ div is the one that matched first.  When you call `.text()` on the outer div then _every_ (non-text) child element of that div will get destroyed.

Comment: Thank you @Alnitak, you learn something new every day. I have updated to code to handle multilevel div's

Comment: ok, so you've _mostly_ just copied my code verbatim, and then added a chunk that appears completely unnecessary?  There's no need to examine the children and the `$('div')` selector will do that anyway.

Comment: I thought I would try your code, it did not work as I would have expected so I modified it. If I had simply copied it verbatim (try it) all the elements in the top level divs removed but it does not modify the children so <div>asdjh alsdhj kamal lakshd <div>bob kamal <div>bob kamal <div>bob kamal</div></div></div>​ only the first kamal gets removed, my modification gets them all. This should be a complement, I looked one of your possible answers, neither of which quite work but gave me the idea to expanded on it to make it work in the situation requested. btw I +1'ed you for the direction

Answer (score 1):

```
var $div = $('div');
$div.text($div.text().replace('yourword', ''))
```

Comment: function parameter version>>??

Comment: @elclanrs see my answer for the function parameter version

Answer (score 0):

The remove function remove a node from the DOM not only her content

try `$('div).text().replace('kamal','');`

edit : this one is working

```
$('div').text($('div').text().replace('kamal', ''));
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qH4CJ/

Comment: I like that the DOM is a "she"

Comment: in french node is a female type :D

Comment: you're right this one is not working, i'm testing a new one, coming back when working

Comment: use a foreach loop on div selector or a regex in this case

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
 $('#cl').click(function(){
        $('div').each(function(){
            $(this).text($(this).text().replace(/kamal/g, '');
          });
 });
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `text()` gets the value, and `text( "someValue" )` sets the value, you just place one inside the other.
This should work for you

https://jsfiddle.net/nnsP4/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#cl').click(function(){
      $('div:contains("kamal")').each(function(){
         var text = $(this).text();
         var newValue =  text.replace('kamal', '');
          $(this).text(newValue);
      });
   });
});
```

Comment: 1. `.text(function(index, value))` is better, and 2. this won't work if the div of interest is inside another div

Comment: i would like to know
why this won't work if the div of interest is inside another div?
this will target each div with matching criteria

Comment: because `<div><div>kamal</div><a href='#'>test</a></div>` would match on the outer div, and your code would convert it to `<div>test</div>`.  All of the inner tags have been destroyed.

Comment: thank you i didn't thought this.
and i will not forgot this now :)

Answer (score -1):

You can use replace method

```
$('#cl').click(function(){
        $('div').text($('div').text().replace('kamal',''));
});
```

Comment: You still need to assign the replacement back to the `$('div')`